End month balance and calculate supportable
I tried looking for some solution here, but still stuck.
WITH MyData AS (
    SELECT 'Jun 2024' AS [date], 'A' AS [group], 69 AS Supply, 0 AS Forecast
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Jul 2024', 'A', 61, 0
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Aug 2024', 'A', 333, 0
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Sep 2024', 'A', 57, 21
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Oct 2024', 'A', 49, 29
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Aug 2024', 'B', 0, 18
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Sep 2024', 'B', 0, 287
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Oct 2024', 'B', 171, 21
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Nov 2024', 'B', 0, 6
)

SELECT 
    cast (MyData.[date] as DATE) as DATE,
    MyData.[group],
    MyData.Forecast,
    MyData.Supply,
    SUM(MyData.Supply - MyData.Forecast) OVER (
        PARTITION BY MyData.[group]
        ORDER BY cast (MyData.[date] as DATE)
    ) AS Balance
FROM MyData
ORDER BY MyData.[group], cast (MyData.[date] as DATE);

Here is my Result
enter image description here
I need to calculate a Supportable logic is if Balance >= 0 then Forecast
Note that group B balance all negative, however, i have 171 in Oct => Supportable is 21 and so on.
enter image description here
Please give me some idea how to achieve that

Consider providing a table of the expected results.

People here are not interested to open unknown url's and risk to land somewhere they don't want. People also dislike writing down all the text from screenshots as they can't copy it. So please provide both sample input data and expected result as tables with text in your question.

Which dbms are you using? Different products have different possibilities.

You can use a CASE statement to achieve the Supportable logic.
Here's the modified query -
WITH MyData AS (
SELECT 'Jun 2024' AS [date], 'A' AS [group], 69 AS Supply, 0 AS Forecast
UNION ALL SELECT 'Jul 2024', 'A', 61, 0
UNION ALL SELECT 'Aug 2024', 'A', 333, 0
UNION ALL SELECT 'Sep 2024', 'A', 57, 21
UNION ALL SELECT 'Oct 2024', 'A', 49, 29
UNION ALL SELECT 'Aug 2024', 'B', 0, 18
UNION ALL SELECT 'Sep 2024', 'B', 0, 287
UNION ALL SELECT 'Oct 2024', 'B', 171, 21
UNION ALL SELECT 'Nov 2024', 'B', 0, 6
)
SELECT 
cast (MyData.[date] as DATE) as DATE,
MyData.[group],
MyData.Forecast,
MyData.Supply,
SUM(MyData.Supply - MyData.Forecast) OVER (
    PARTITION BY MyData.[group]
    ORDER BY cast (MyData.[date] as DATE)
) AS Balance,
CASE 
    WHEN SUM(MyData.Supply - MyData.Forecast) OVER (
        PARTITION BY MyData.[group]
        ORDER BY cast (MyData.[date] as DATE)
    ) >= 0 THEN MyData.Forecast
    ELSE NULL
END AS Supportable
FROM MyData
ORDER BY MyData.[group], cast (MyData.[date] as DATE);

here is the fiddle link click here

Hi @Alvaro,
Thank you for quick reply.
However, the logic CASE statement is correct in case i dont have Supply come in month later.
For Oct-24, i have supply of 171, which can support 21 and 6 in Nov.
How can i override CASE statement when i have some supply coming later?

You can use a subquery to calculate the total supply for each group that is available in the future, and then use that in your case statement.

I'm thinking how can i 'reset' supply col when it hit some value. but still not find the solution yet

https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=e56635d2-0a26-42c5-b4a5-a8b4342c7df7    See the modified changes

can you please tell me more how to use subquery to calculate total supply which available in future?

https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=e56635d2-0a26-42c5-b4a5-a8b4342c7df7  See the code for the subquery to calculate the total future supply available
